# Issue with integrating mapbox gl js in angular 8 web app

Tags: angular, mapbox

I am trying to integrate mapbox into my basic web app but am having issues when trying to add. So far I have generated a mapbox service and map component.

I tried taking an example from mapbox and placing that code in my map.component.html file but when I do that the div for that area of the screen comes up blank.

Could be a css/styling issue I mixed or could be a angular issue. Open to suggestions for troubleshooting. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Post the code that would be great to help you. Cheers :)

Comment: If the code is too long you can upload it or a part of it to https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @German Quinteros and Raja - 

Sorry for the delay in answering you guys. I was finally able to figure this out thanks to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624792/mapbox-gl-js-map-is-undefined-in-angular-cli-project-on-load-event)

I was initiating the variables for my map file in ngOnInit and ended up adding the following binding statement:

`this.map.on("load", this.onLoad.bind(this));`

Adding that line in my ngOnInit allowed me to then use this.map to add layers etc. Stay safe during these chaotic time gents. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @304techmaven great to hear that you were able to figure out.
I think it would be nice if you can add the answer to the question and then mark as resolved. In order, it would be useful for someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this issue, hopefully it will help anyone that has similar issues.

Answer is centered around the below command:

`this.map.on("load", this.onLoad.bind(this));`

Pasting this command in the ngOnInit function allowed me to bind the public map variable in my map.component.ts file to be called in a function called "onLoad()" where I added layers via Mapbox's syntax and addLayer/addSource methods.

This [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624792/mapbox-gl-js-map-is-undefined-in-angular-cli-project-on-load-event) also explains the onLoad() function and integration well.

If you are having issues with integrating mapbox into your angular stack definitely reach out below. Cheers!